# Memory usage on 64 bit Linux System is twice than the MAC 32 bit

Tags: java, linux, 64-bit, jboss5.x

We are trying to deploy an application in JBOSS 5.01 version with jdk 1.5_22 version on 64 bit Linux OS .The java process is taking almost twice the memory when compared to the 32 bit jvm running on MAC OS.
Will there be any patch to the Linux 64 bit System?
Or why is it behaving like this?
We are aware that the 64 bit takes more memory.Can some one point us to an article from Oracle where it says this is the memory footprint on 64 bit when compared to 32 bit

Comment: Pointers are twice as large. Any other questions?

Comment: How are you measuring the memory usage (on each system)?

Answer (score 4):

With the Java 6 VM, you can try adding UseCompressedOops, which will reduce the size of the pointers.

`java -XX:+UseCompressedOops ...`

http://wikis.sun.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops

Comment: We had tried this option but the memory change was very negligible .We had tried increasing the heap size also using the Xmx option .Would like to know if there is some article or link from oracle(Sun) that certifies the same

Answer (score 3):

Are you explicitly setting the max heap size with `-Xmx`? If not, note that [default heap size](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#64bit_heap_defaults) is larger on 64-bit than on 32-bit, in addition to the larger pointers.